# Launch an H2O cluster on localhost

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to launch an H2O cluster on localhost but is taking too long to start a connection. This is the code I am using:

```
    pkgs <- c("methods","statmod","stats","graphics","RCurl","jsonlite","tools","utils")
    for (pkg in pkgs) {
      if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
    }
    install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turchin/8/R")))
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
```

What I have in the console is:

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /var/folders/0c/2vddb1fs58q9tms_p7qzp2v00000gn/T//RtmpqOJp73/h2o_name_started_from_r.out
    /var/folders/0c/2vddb1fs58q9tms_p7qzp2v00000gn/T//RtmpqOJp73/h2o_name_started_from_r.err

    java version "9.0.1"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

    Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ...
```

### No errors are produced but it seems to be not working. what can I do?

I update this question because now an error has been shown:

```
Error: Unable to establish connection with R session
```

Comment: What do the logs say? http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/logs.html

Comment: Should I go to Logging in R section?

Comment: Yes. I believe so.

Comment: I can't run other commands while it hasn't finished yet.

Comment: If you are running the h2o cluster on your local machine, you should be able to `cat` or `tail` the log files listed in the console. Open up another console window and try `cat /var/folders/0c/2vddb1fs58q9tms_p7qzp2v00000gn/T//RtmpqOJp73/h2o_name_started_from_r.out`

Comment: It says no such file or directory 
Appending: No such file or directory
REST: No such file or directory
API: No such file or directory
transactions: No such file or directory
to: No such file or directory
log: No such file or directory
file: No such file or directory
/var/folders/0c/2vddb1fs58q9tms_p7qzp2v00000gn/T//RtmpnHMEOx/rest.log: No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188933/discussion-between-user233531-and-richard).

Answer (score 0):

Java 9 is a poor version of Java to use (for really anything at all).

I recommend using Java 8, which many, many people do use.